# Adding bibliography to table of contents in scrreprt, using biblatex and biber

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, koma-script, biber

EDIT: The cause for the problem described below was that [the .bbl file was being emptied every time the document compiled.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179420/3465)

---

I'm attempting to add my renamed bibliography as an unnumbered top-level (chapter) entry to the table of contents (TOC) in my document, but so far all of my attempts have been unsuccessful. Below is an MWE for my latest and tidiest attempt, plus the output. Does anyone know what my code is missing? I'm using MiKTeX 2.9, Biblatex 2.8, Biber 1.8, and I've made sure all my other packages are up to date as well. I'm using the pdflatex compiler.

---

### Main document

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \cite{entry}.

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title=References]

\end{document}
```

---

### test.bib

```
@article{entry,
author = {John Doe},
journal = {TeX Monthly},
pages = {1----10},
title = {{How do I get this to work?}},
volume = {99},
year = {1234}
}
```

---

### Output

[image: TOC]

[image: Bibliography]

---

I tried working around the problem by adding the line

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
```

just after the `printbibliography` command, but this causes the TOC to reference the bibliography one page early. And besides, it is only a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: I get this : http://i.stack.imgur.com/94mgs.png. You don't have to use `[bibliography=totoc]` in the options of `\documentclass` when you write `heading=bibintoc` in `\printbibliography`. May be updating will help?

Comment: @HarishKumar, that is very strange. The provided MWE does not give a bibliography entry in the table of contents, and everything I use should be up to date. I've updated the question with these details.

Comment: mine is miktex 2.9 too. And `biblatex.sty    2013/11/25 v2.8a programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex2.sty    2013/11/25 v2.8a programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB
)` and biber v 1.8.

Comment: I can copy that, works on my system (same as @HarishKumar)